# How to get the row number of selected row of jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to get the row number from datatable and pass in to some update function.Some time it giving row number as [Object object] Here is my code:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () 
{
var idx = table.row( this ).index();
alert(idx);//Some times it alerts [Object object] 
}
```

Comment: Can you create [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) reproducing (at least "sometimes") mentioned problem with this code which is from [docs](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row().index()) and is supposed to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use

```
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () 
{
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var rowindex = tr.index();

     alert(rowindex);
});
```

this way you'll have the index value of the row.

Comment: @Telmo Silva: the above solutions produces the index based on the row clicked but not on the row selected right? as in, If I select a row the above code will work and again If I select the same row again to make it as 'Deselect' then the selected row index should be null or -1.... so how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#example ").dataTable().find("tbody").on('click', 'tr', function () {
        alert(this.rowIndex);
    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/LsSXy/245/)